# object reuse and composition in json schemas

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I have a json blob which looks something like this;

```
{
     "ObjectA":
      {
          "Object1": {fields},
          "Object2": {fields},
          "Object3": {fields}
      },
      "ObjectB":
      {
          "Object1": {fields},
          "Object2": {fields},
          "Object3": {fields}
      }
}
```

Is there a way I can define Object's 1, 2 and 3 once and reuse them within the schema? Can this be done with a json schema? I'd like to write it like I would it's C# equivalent where the numbered objects are only defined once and then the letter objects are composed of them.

EDIT: For clarification I'm trying to correct an existing schema. The schema defines the numbered objects in every letter object even though they all have the exact same definition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution in the docs.

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor7

Schemas can have sub schemas. So my code now looks like;

```
  "ObjectB":
  {
      "Object1": {"title":"object1"},
      "Object2": {"title":"object2"},
      "Object3": {"title":"object3"}
  }
```

Then out side of that schema

```
{
    "Object1": {
         "title":"object1",
          //20 more lines of json
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit old, but if you're looking for the exact spec for subschemas, it's here http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.4.5