# Reusing JSON subschema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am needing to use a sub schema multiple times in my JSON file, but haven't been able to figure out the correct way to structure the schema file such that I am able to get the schema validation on all the sub properties instead of just the property that I list in the schema file.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349754/object-reuse-and-composition-in-json-schemas) was getting at a similar question, but the answer didn't make much sense/I wasn't sure if or how I could use the same method here. Am I thinking too much in the OOP mindset with multiple instances of a single class?

Here is more or less what I am trying to do

```json
{
    "Object1": {
        "Title": "Some Title",
        "Description": "Some Description"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "Title": "Another title",
        "Description": "Another Description"
    }
// unknown number of objects but each object should have the same sub schema
}
```

Here is what I have thus far

```json
{
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "required": [
        "Object1"
    ],
    "title": "The root schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Object1": {
            "required": [
                "Title",
                "Description"
            ],
            "title": "The Reusable Object schema",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Title": {
                    "title": "The Title schema",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Description": {
                    "title": "The Description schema",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": true
}
```

Comment: I don't actually think the question and answer you linked to in your question is very clear on the problem or solution. I don't think it's likely to help you. Pretty sure I can though! But, I need to know: Do you want it to apply to ALL the value objects of your root object, or just some (you can use a regex on the key for conditional application)

Comment: Great question, thanks for asking! The value objects would all follow the same schema. And hopefully to provide some context on why I am trying to do this, I am trying to create a JSON file that can be read to dynamically build a set of svelte components based on the value objects. So for each object in the root element, a svelte component would be created and the object's values would be passed in as props to the component. So in the example above, a custom component would be created for each key, then the values in `Title` and `Description` would be passed in to fill out the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all values of the object should follow the schema, the solution is quite simple.

First, you have to remember how `additionalProperties` works...

> The value of "additionalProperties" MUST be a valid JSON Schema.
>
> This keyword determines how child instances validate for objects,
> and    does not directly validate the immediate instance itself.
>
> Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the child
> values of instance names that do not match any names in "properties",
> and do not match any regular expression in "patternProperties".
>
> For all such properties, validation succeeds if the child instance
> validates against the "additionalProperties" schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.6

So, now we know that `additionalProperties` takes a JSON Schema, and not just booleans (booleans are valid JSON Schema), the solution might be a little obvious.

Remove the outermost `additionalPropertie`, rename `properties` to `additionalProperties`, and remove the key `Object1` and object braces.

The result is the following...

```
...
"title": "The root schema",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "required": [
      "Title",
      "Description"
    ],
...
```

Live demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/pqwCc

I don't know what you would want to do with the outer most `required` though. I guess remove it, as you don't know in advance what the keys will be.

Maybe you want to use `minProperties` to make sure there is at least one?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize you can pass a schema into additionalProperties section. That's super useful. Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: For those who don't get why the validation is broken like I was — https://jsonschema.dev/s/oBjEg with typo fixed.

Comment: What was the typo? (And thanks!!)